# Delete duplicate line in multiple text file (loop)

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, cygwin

I have a large directory with multiple text file, and each text file contains multiple lines. I'm trying to create a loop to check each text file against the other and remove duplicates values.

For example lets say i have 3 text files.

File1.txt

```
1
2
3
4
```

File2.txt

```
3
4
5
6
```

File3.txt

```
6
7
8
```

first i want to check **File1.txt** against File2.txt and remove duplicates values from File2.txt.

Next, **File1.txt** with File3.txt

and then **File2.txt** with File1.txt

**File2.txt** with File3.txt

...etc

I'm using `grep -vf File1.txt File2.txt > File2.txt` to remove duplicates values in files, but i'm not sure how to put it in a loop.

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
for f in *.txt; do
for f2 in *.txt; do
grep -vf $f $f2 > $f.txt;
done
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `sort -u` command will produce a sorted unique list.

Comment: what is the end result?

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion in your approach.  I think this is what you need:

Assume unique entries within each file, so each file can represent a set,

let `A \ B` defines set difference (remove common elements from `A`).  Then, simply

```
file1.new = file1
file2.new = file2 \ file1
file3.new = (file3 \ file1) \ file2
```

there is no need to loop back and do file1 and file2 again.

Converting to code:

```
$ function diff() { grep -vFf "$2" "$1"; }
$ cp file1 file1.new
$ diff file2 file1 > file2.new
$ diff <(diff file3 file1) file2 > file3.new

$ head file?.new

==> file1.new <==
1
2
3
4

==> file2.new <==
5
6

==> file3.new <==
7
8
```